# How to insert multiples arrays with multiples values in laravel by query builder

Tags: insert

lets suppose i want to insert an array which container following data;

here is an array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => ::1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => 2018-10-11
    [5] => 2018-10-31
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 2018-10-11
    [9] => 10:38:36
)
```

but i am stuck how to insert this array with single foreach loop

and i am using this code but not working for multi arrays with different values

```
$count_row = 0;
foreach($products as $row){
    $count_row ++;
    //Set Field data according to table column
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'ip_address' => $ip_address,
        'product_id' => $row,
        'page_id' => $row[$count_row],
        'start_date' => $start_date,
        'end_date' => $end_date,
        'type' => $type,
        'status' => $status,
        'created_date' => $created_date,
        'created_time' => $created_time,
    );

    //Query For Inserting Data
    $query = DB::table('tbl_product_advertisements')
                 ->insertGetId($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, for inserting this type of array we have to use 2 loops,

Comment: You should put this as a comment. Please update your question so others will understand what you were trying to achieve and how you solved it